# The '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' karma plugin is meant to be used from within Angular CLI and will not work correctly outside of it

Tags: angular

When i am trying to config and run the `.sh` file in local environment, getting this error:

> Error: The '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma' karma plugin is meant to be used from within Angular CLI and will not work correctly outside of it.

I tried to use CLI but its not worked for me.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

The following file I have created to execute karma.

`run_unit_test.sh`

`./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start src/karma.conf.js`

Comment: Can you share the content of file run_unit_test.sh?

Comment: ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start src/karma.conf.js

Answer (score 6):

I got this error in my WebStorm and I noticed that in

**Run/Debug Configurations** — **Karma package**  input, was wrong package path - `path_to_project/node_modules/karma`

Error gone when I set it to: `path_to_project/node_modules/@angular/cli`

*I know that I'm late with this answer and that this doesn't quite fit your situation.
But I know that people with a similar problem often get here and I will leave this post for them.*

Answer (score 1):

For me wrapping this call into `ng` fixed it:

`ng test --karma-config src/karma.conf.js`

[It seems this was a break sometime around angular 6 release.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10703)

In my case specifically I actually used

`ng test --karma-config karma.conf.js --browsers Chrome_with_debugging`